# git merge branch to tag - patch for an old release

Tags: git, git-merge

I've got three branches, `v3.0` `v3.1` and `master`.

Master is currently running the same as v3.1 as that is the branch that's currently in development. v3.0 is the current release, and I need to do a patch to that release.

I've checked out v3.0, completed the changes and created the patch tag e.g. `v3.0.1`. All pushed etc.

I'm now trying to merge the v3.0 changes to the patch tag v3.0.1 but it's saying it's already up to date. When I checkout the patch tag, it does not have the new patch changes, instead it is the old v3.0.

What I'm trying:

```
[v3.0] git merge v3.0.1
Already up to date.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you draw a sample graph?

Answer (score 0):

Git is telling you that your v3.0 branch is already an ancestor of v3.0.1, so there is nothing for it to merge.

If instead you want to backport changes from v3.1, then you’ll need to merge from that branch.